# Assigning scalar values for PID for order in Neural Network

Tags: neural-network, feature-selection, feature-engineering, windows

I have built a neural network using Windows Process's I started off with only two features, the file path with parent process, and the file path with child process.  I am slowly adding features for instance I just added the destination user name independent variable so my dataset looks like this before it goes through label encoding and dummy variables:

```
    ParentProcess                           ChildProcess           Suspicous
0   C:\Program Files\Splunk\bin\splunkd.exe C:\Program Files\Splunk\bin\splunk-optimize.exe 0
1   C:\Windows\cmd.exe  C:\Windows\System32\backgroundTaskHost.exe  1
2   C:\Program Files\Splunk\bin\splunkd.exe C:\Program Files\Splunk\bin\splunk-optimize.exe 0
3   C:\Program Files (x86)\Citrix\ICA Client\SelfS...   C:\Windows\System32\book.pdf ...    1
4   C:\Windows\System32\svchost.exe C:\Windows\System32\gpupdate.exe    0
7   C:\Windows\System32\cmd.exe C:\Windows\System32\cscript.exe 0
```

I would like to add process ID's available to me as features or in pre-processing somehow so that the model can learn whether the order kicks off normally or is anomalous.  It would sort of look like a tree.  Where smss.exe kicks off smss.exe, csrss.exe, wininit.exe, and winlogon.exe.  The smss.exe and csrss.exe processes die but winitit.exe and winlogon.exe that were children become parents of other processes, all tracked by process id's.  I would like to assign smss.exe a 1 then crss.exe, wininit.exe, and winlogon.exe a 2 and so on.  Some processes will be 3 and so on and some processes will die at 2.

```
Example:

smss.exe (1) PID = 1050 -> winit.exe (2) PID = 18888, winlogon.exe (2) PID = 9522
winit.exe (2) PID = 18888 -> services.exe (3) PID = 20000, lsass.exe (3) PID = 20001
winlogon.exe (2) PID = 9522 -> userinit.exe (3) PID 11224
services.exe (3) PID = 20000 -> svchost.exe (4) PID 25001
```

Is there a way to use something like this in a neural network kind of like you would in a time series?  Or have the neural net learn these numbers?  Or have seen something like this being done like an m-tree style or scalar value for depth?